# Qt Creator - Can't use debugger: program.exe not in executable format: File format not recognized

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Using Qt version 5.7.0 for Desktop Windows 10

I can run can't use the debug option (F5), it displays in a dialog:

```
"D:/DEV Programas/build-GIFS-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug/debug/GIFS.exe": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

I can't use at all the debugger. What can I do?

Sorry I don't display more information. I don't know much how Qt Creator works and what info you may need to help me.

Comment: So can you build/compile the project without errors?

Comment: It compiles and executes when I run it (Ctrl+R) correctly.

Comment: Does it happen on any projects (if needed try Qt's example projects), or only for one in particular? If its the first, you might want to ask on Qt's forum

Comment: You are trying to debug a binary compiled in Release mode. Have you tried to compile it in Debug mode?

Comment: @Bettorun I've tried example projects, they also fail at debugging.

Comment: @jpo38 I think I'm using the debug mode, like this:  http://image.prntscr.com/image/94e8fa54ae5344cdb7ecc009b306eebc.png

Comment: in the menu go to tools->options->Debuggers and see if you have any debugger installed.

Comment: @basslo Yes, I have. 1st is GNU gdb 7.10.1 for MinGW 5.3.0 32bit (Default on Qt I guess), 2nd and 3rd (I've downloaded and installed them today before asking here to see if I could make it work), they are (Auto-detected) CDB from Windows Kits, one x86 and the other x64. All three appear on Tools->Options->Debuggers.

Comment: @SkwisgaarFC: If you selected "Debug", it's wierd that it tries to execute `build-GIFS-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Release/release/GIFS.exe` which is apparently Release

Comment: ok i see what is the problem you are compiling in debug mode but running the release .exe. You should change the .exe in the project configuration choosing the one that is in the Debug directory and it will work.

Comment: @jpo38 I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, when I select "Debug" it uses the .exe debug path; selecting "Release" it uses the release path.

Comment: @SkwisgaarFC: Then update your post. Because it shows you tryin gto debug a release binary...

Answer (score 0):

you are in debug mode for build, but you are running the release executable you have to configure Qt Creator ->Project->run and the Add->custom Executable then choose the executable inside you debug directory see picture below

[image]

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/dc665ae7e4b24ca08c151ce67a20d9b7.png   I've done exactly what you said, though the same dialog error occurrs. I also select the new .exe added when I followed your instructions.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of error dialog please.

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/ca0f10af7afd427b8b834238c3221406.png     Maybe there's something wrong with the .pro file and I have to add something (I'm a Qt beginner). The .pro file can be seen in the image.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the pro. try to clean the project the run Qmake and try again. If it doesn't work provide screenshot of the directory containing the .exe and the Kit your are using to build (by going in the menu to Tools->options select Build & Run in the left menu then select the kit tab and select the Kit you're using to display the information the one with (default)

Comment: Cleaned and ran QMake. Files:   http://image.prntscr.com/image/bd9375598cb846c3a8858a1f50586bbe.png   Build&Run:   http://image.prntscr.com/image/b38ee64165424285a9a859314751447c.png

Answer (score -1):

I've found the solution. I "just" had to reinstall Qt. Not Qt creator, but the framework itself. Now I can use the debugger.

Comment: ok cool because your configuration was ok. So there was no reason why it wasn't working.